# Can I use Azure DocumentAnalysisClient with no credentials?

Tags: python, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to use azure's document analysis client but I don't use credentials for my form recognizer. I can make a simple request call to it and it works fine, like so:

```
import requests
my_endpoint = "http://form_recognizer...?api-version=2022-08-31"
data = "some data"
params = "some params"
requests.post(my_endpoint, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}, data=data, params=params)
```

The request works and it gives me the results I need. However, I would prefer to use `DocumentAnalysisClient` because it comes with several methods that would save me weeks of coding. However, this class requires a `credential` argument but I am not using credentials for this endpoint. It is an open HTTP endpoint, so how exactly can I use the class without providing any credentials?

```
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

client = DcoumentAnalysisClient(endpoint=my_endpoint, credential=...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use Azure DocumentAnalysisClient with no credentials?

According to this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ai-formrecognizer-readme?view=azure-python#authenticate-the-client), it is not possible to access **`DocumentAnalysisClient`** without credentials.

The `DocumentAnalysisClient` requires a credential to authenticate with the Azure service, either with **`AzureKeyCredential`** or **`Azure Active Directory credential`**.

For key credential, you need to pass the **`key`** of your Document intelligence AI service.

**Code:**

```
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

endpoint = "<Your-endpoint>"
credential = AzureKeyCredential("")
client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=credential)
```

For Active Directory credential, you need to use azure-identity to authenticate with Document intelligence AI service.

**Code:**

```
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential 

endpoint = "<Your-Endpoint>"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential() 
client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint, credential)
```

Now, using the above authentication process, you can build all intelligent document processing solutions.

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Document Intelligence (formerly Form Recognizer) SDKs - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/quickstarts/get-started-sdks-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&pivots=programming-language-rest-api)